# How to get the search mask entered on the Powershell command line?

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell drive provider in c#, following [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/prog-guide/creating-a-windows-powershell-navigation-provider?view=powershell-7.1).

I'm stuck in the implementation of [GetChildItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.containercmdletprovider.getchilditems?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), which is the method that PowerShell calls in order to determine what files are contained within a directory.  This method gets called when, for example, the user types `dir *.*`.

I want to be able to filter the resultset by the `*.*` portion of the command, but as far as I can tell, it is not exposed to `GetChildItems`. Where can I get it?

```
protected override void GetChildItems(string path, bool recurse)
{
    var searchOption = recurse ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
    var searchMask = //Where do I get this from?

    foreach (var itemPath in Directory.GetFiles(path, searchMask, searchOption))
    {
        var file = GetFile(itemPath); 
        WriteItemObject(file, itemPath, false);
    }
}
```

TLDR: In the code above, how can I populate `searchMask` with the argument that was entered on the commandline?

**More information**

This is how the provider class is declared.

```
[CmdletProvider("Foo", ProviderCapabilities.Filter | ProviderCapabilities.Include)]
public class FooDriveProvider : NavigationCmdletProvider, IContentCmdletProvider
{
```

Comment: Is this what youre looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0

Comment: @AbrahamZinala No. I am trying to figure out how to obtain the arguments that would be passed to that method, i.e. the search argument that was entered on the Powershell command line.

Comment: @DougMaurer Not sure I understand. You can't change the signature of a method when you override it. Even if I could, I have no idea what to add to the signature to get the PowerShell environment to pass what is needed.

Comment: I guess you can read these masks from `Include` and `Exclude` properties of  [CmdletProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.cmdletprovider?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) base class.

Comment: There's also the [`Filter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.cmdletprovider.filter#System_Management_Automation_Provider_CmdletProvider_Filter) property, which gets its value from the `-Filter` parameter, which is meant to be implemented by each provider for efficient, at-the-source filtering. In the `FileSystem` provider it is used for wildcard matching by the underlying file-system APIs, as opposed to post-hoc wildcard-processing by PowerShell itself, which applies to `-Include`, `-Exclude`.

Comment: Well if anyone can answer it’s mklement0 or @mathias

Comment: Been testing these. So far, the `Include` property is always either null or an empty collection by the time execution reaches `GetChildItems()`. Also, `Filter` is coming back empty.

Comment: Is your provider class declared with the attribute [CmdletProviderAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Provider.CmdletProviderAttribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) containing `Include` and `Filter` [ProviderCapabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.provider.providercapabilities?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)?

Comment: @ruslan.gilmutdinov Yes. I've updated my post to include the class's declaration.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to filter, your provider class must:

1. Include the attribute `CmdletProviderAttribute` containing `ProviderCapabilities.Filter` in the class declaration, i.e. `[CmdletProvider("Foo", ProviderCapabilities.Filter)]`;
2. Derive from the `ContainerCmdletProvider` (or `NavigationCmdletProvider`) base class;
3. Implement methods `IsValidPath`, `ItemExists`, and `GetChildItems`. The implementation of `ItemExists` and `GetChildItems` methods needs to ensure that the path passed to the method meets filter requirements. These methods should access the `CmdletProvider.Filter` property and use it for filtering.

As an example of implementation, you can look at the [ZipFileProvider](https://gist.github.com/rgilmutdinov/1286739c455744f27d3f69c8c435ce4e), which provides the ability to list the contents of zip archives.

You can use this provider with the following commands:

```
// Import module compiled from the sources to the current session
Import-Module ./PSZip.dll

// Create new drive referring to .zip archive
New-PSDrive -Name "ZIP" -PSProvider "ZipFile" -Root "D:\files\archive.zip"

// List zip archive contents
Get-ChildItem -Path ZIP: -Recurse

// List only *.txt files
Get-ChildItem -Path ZIP: -Recurse -Filter *.txt

// ...or
dir ZIP: -Recurse *.txt
```